# Scrape table from webpage when in <div> format - using Beautiful Soup

Tags: html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

So I'm aiming to scrape 2 tables (in different formats) from a website - https://info.fsc.org/details.php?id=a0240000005sQjGAAU&type=certificate after using the search bar to iterate this over a list of license codes. I haven't included the loop fully yet but I added it at the top for completeness.

My issue is that because the two tables I want, Product Data and Certificate Data are in 2 different formats, so I have to scrape them separately. As the Product data is in the normal "tr" format on the webpage, this bit is easy and I've managed to extract a CSV file of this. The harder bit is extracting Certificate Data, as it is in "div" form.

I've managed to print the Certificate Data as a list of text, using the class function, however I need to have it in a tabular form saved in a CSV file. As you can see, I've tried several unsuccessful ways of converting it to a CSV but  If you have any suggestions, it would be much appreciated, thank you!! Also any other general tips to improve my code would be great too, as I am new to web-scraping.

```
#namelist = open('example.csv', newline='', delimiter = 'example')
#for name in namelist:
    #include all of the below

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/jamesozden/Downloads/chromedriver")
url = "https://info.fsc.org/certificate.php"
driver.get(url)

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="code"]')
search_bar.send_keys("FSC-C001777")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
new_url = driver.current_url

r = requests.get(new_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
df, = pd.read_html(str(table))
certificate = soup.find(class_= 'certificatecl').text
##certificate1 = pd.read_html(str(certificate))

driver.quit()

df.to_csv("Product_Data.csv", index=False)
##certificate1.to_csv("Certificate_Data.csv", index=False)

#print(df[0].to_json(orient='records'))
print certificate
```

Output:

```
Status
Valid
First Issue Date
2009-04-01
Last Issue Date
2018-02-16
Expiry Date
2019-04-01
Standard
FSC-STD-40-004 V3-0
```

What I want but over hundreds/thousands of license codes (I just manually created this one sample in Excel):

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzbS7.png)

**EDIT**

So whilst this is now working for Certificate Data, I also want to scrape the Product Data and output that into another .csv file. However currently it is only printing 5 copies of the product data for the final license code which is not what I want.

New Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("MS_License_Codes.csv")
codes = df["License Code"]

def get_data_by_code(code):
    data = [
        ('code', code),
        ('submit', 'Search'),
    ]

    response = requests.post('https://info.fsc.org/certificate.php', data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

    status = soup.find_all("label", string="Status")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text
    first_issue_date = soup.find_all("label", string="First Issue Date")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text
    last_issue_date = soup.find_all("label", string="Last Issue Date")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text
    expiry_date = soup.find_all("label", string="Expiry Date")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text
    standard = soup.find_all("label", string="Standard")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text


    return [code, status, first_issue_date, last_issue_date, expiry_date, standard]

# Just insert here output filename and codes to parse...
OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = 'Certificate_Data.csv'
#codes = ['C001777', 'C001777', 'C001777', 'C001777']


df3=pd.DataFrame()


with open(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for code in codes:
        print('Getting code# {}'.format(code))
        writer.writerow((get_data_by_code(code)))
        table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
        df1, = pd.read_html(str(table))
        df3 = df3.append(df1) 

df3.to_csv('Product_Data.csv', index = False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Comment: @Selçuk Done! I've added it to my original question.

Comment: @Selçuk I'm not sure if you wanted my actual output so I added an example of the format I would like, with one I just manually created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's all you need.
No chromedriver. No pandas. Forget about it in context of scraping.

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# This is all what you need for your task. Really.
# No chromedriver. Don't use it for scraping. EVER.
# No pandas. Don't use it for writing csv. It's not what pandas was made for.

#Function to parse single data page based on single input code.
def get_data_by_code(code):

    # Parameters to build POST-request. 
    # "type" and "submit" params are static. "code" is your desired code to scrape.
    data = [
        ('type', 'certificate'),
        ('code', code),
        ('submit', 'Search'),
    ]

    # POST-request to gain page data.
    response = requests.post('https://info.fsc.org/certificate.php', data=data)
    # "soup" object to parse html data.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

    # "status" variable. Contains first's found [LABEL tag, with text="Status"] following sibling DIV text. Which is status.
    status = soup.find_all("label", string="Status")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text
    # Same for issue dates... etc.
    first_issue_date = soup.find_all("label", string="First Issue Date")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text
    last_issue_date = soup.find_all("label", string="Last Issue Date")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text
    expiry_date = soup.find_all("label", string="Expiry Date")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text
    standard = soup.find_all("label", string="Standard")[0].find_next_sibling('div').text

    # Returning found data as list of values.
    return [response.url, status, first_issue_date, last_issue_date, expiry_date, standard]

# Just insert here output filename and codes to parse...
OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = 'output.csv'
codes = ['C001777', 'C001777', 'C001777', 'C001777']

with open(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for code in codes:
        print('Getting code# {}'.format(code))

        #Writing list of values to file as single row.
        writer.writerow((get_data_by_code(code)))
```

Everything is really straightforward here. I'd suggest you spend some time in Chrome dev tools "network" tab to have a better understanding of request forging, which is a must for scraping tasks.

[image]

In general, you don't need to run chrome to click the "search" button, you need to forge request generated by this click. Same for any form and ajax.

Comment: Thank you so much, that runs so much quicker now! One question, do you mind explaining the data part of your function? I'm trying to understand what you've done and can't quite figure out what the 'type', 'certificate' etc are for.. is it just the necessary parameters for the request function?

Comment: Updated my answer with some comments.

Comment: I have one more issue, I also want to scrape the table on the page, which is in my code using the table and df variables (see edited question). Although this works for a single page, it seems to give me an error which I can't seem to resolve.

Comment: I've asked another question as it might be easier to see what my issue, I would appreciate anymore support!

Answer (score 0):

well... you should sharpen your skills (:

```
df3=pd.DataFrame()

with open(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for code in codes:
        print('Getting code# {}'.format(code))
        writer.writerow((get_data_by_code(code)))
        ### HERE'S THE PROBLEM:
        # "soup" variable is declared inside of "get_data_by_code" function.
        # So you can't use it in outer context.
        table = soup.find_all('table')[0] # <--- you should move this line to 
        #definition of "get_data_by_code" function and return it's value somehow...
        df1, = pd.read_html(str(table))
        df3 = df3.append(df1) 

df3.to_csv('Product_Data.csv', index = False, encoding='utf-8')
```

As per example you can return dictionary of values from "get_data_by_code" function:

```
 def get_data_by_code(code):
 ...
     table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
     return dict(row=row, table=table)
```